# Flexbox where one box has set flexBasis with and the others fill remaining space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

Below I have a flexbox row. What I'm trying to achieve is this: I'd like to have a row of 5 boxes and I want to be able to set some of the boxes (not all) specific widths using `flexBasis` (`flex-basis`). Below I have set the first box to `flexBox: 'content'` or `flexBox: '150px'` (a deliberate) size.

**I'm looking for a way for box 2, 3, 4, 5 to all be the same size and take up the full amount of it's parent.**

[image]

```
let {flexContainer, flexBox, custom} = StyleSheet.create({
  flexContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    padding: '30px',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  flexBox: {
    padding: '30px',
    flexBasis: '20%',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  custom: {
    flexBasis: 'content'
  }
})

class SampleApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={flexContainer}>
        <View style={[flexBox, custom]}>
          meow
        </View>
        <View style={flexBox}>
          meowmeow
        </View>
        <View style={flexBox}>
          meowmeowmeow
        </View>
        <View style={flexBox}>
          meow
        </View>
        <View style={flexBox}>
          meow
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}


// rendering
const rootTag = document.getElementById('react-root');
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
AppRegistry.runApplication('SampleApp', { rootTag });
```

http://codepen.io/reggi/pen/xqbZav?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

I believe I stumbled on a possible solution.

By setting the `flexContainer` to `justifyContent: 'space-between'` and the `flexBox` `flexBasis: '20%'` you get the functionality I want just with gutters rather than filling all the space.

http://codepen.io/reggi/pen/jBEPXg?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`flex-grow`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-10) to make the elements take up the remaining space. Setting your `flexBox` to `flexGrow: 1` will distribute the remaining space equally to all elements.

```
flexBox: {
  padding: '30px',
  flexBasis: '20%',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  borderColor: 'blue',
  borderWidth: 1,
  flexGrow: 1
}
```

To make your `custom` elements stay the original size, you need to set `flexGrow: 0` on them and they will have exactly the size you specify in `flexBasis`. *Note: I replaced `content` with `150px`, because `content` is not supported by most browsers (see [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility))*

```
custom: {
  flexBasis: '150px',
  flexGrow: 0
}
```

The updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpYKGq?editors=0010